# umount failure, e2fsck not possible to check for errors

Tags: linux, mount

I am backing up my home computer using an rsync script to a remotely located WD MyCloud.  I have recently found directories on the WD MyCloud that won't delete.  Here is an example:

```
MyHomeCloud:/DataVolume/shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users
/Start Menu/Programs# rm -f Garmin
rm: cannot remove `Garmin': Input/output error
MyHomeCloud:/DataVolume/shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users
/Start Menu/Programs# ls -li
ls: cannot access Garmin: Input/output error
total 4
       ? d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? Garmin
90309235 drwxrwxrwx 3 197608 197121 4096 Dec 26 23:33 Proton Development Suite
MyHomeCloud:/DataVolume/shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users
/Start Menu/Programs#
```

I am hoping these are logical errors and not hardware ones.

The Linux on the WD MyCloud is:

```
uname -a    
Linux MyHomeCloud 3.2.26 #1 SMP Thu Jul 9 11:14:15 PDT 2015 wd-2.4-rel armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The last lines of `dmesg` after a `reboot` are:

```
[   73.079642] Hfs+/HfsJ support included
[   73.079646] optimized: speed
[   73.079649] Build_for__WD_Sequoia_k3.2.26_2015-03-06_lke_9.2.0_r248522_b40
[   73.079655]
[   73.112027] initcall init_module+0x0/0x188 [ufsd] returned 0 after 35758 usecs
[   78.115289] EXT4-fs (sda4): barriers disabled
[   80.394824] EXT4-fs (sda4): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[   81.006617] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode. Opts: acl,user_xattr,data=writeback,barrier=0,init_itable=10
[   81.181229] EXT4-fs (sda4): re-mounted. Opts: user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback
[   98.962509] Adding 500672k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:500672k
[  118.222076] calling  init_module+0x0/0x200 [netatop] @ 6599
[  118.228708] initcall init_module+0x0/0x200 [netatop] returned 0 after 894 usecs
MyHomeCloud:~#
```

That suggests that I need to run `e2fsck`, so then I try to `umount`, first I do this to get more information:

```
MyHomeCloud:~# parted -l /dev/sda?

Model: ATA WDC WD60EFRX-68L (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 6001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 3      15.7MB  528MB   513MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary
 1      528MB   2576MB  2048MB  ext3            primary  raid
 2      2576MB  4624MB  2048MB  ext3            primary  raid
 5      4624MB  4724MB  99.6MB                  primary
 6      4724MB  4824MB  101MB                   primary
 7      4824MB  4826MB  1049kB                  primary
 8      4826MB  4828MB  2097kB                  primary
 4      4828MB  6001GB  5996GB  ext4            primary


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 2048MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2048MB  2048MB  ext3
```

Then I try this:

```
MyHomeCloud:~# umount /dev/sda4
MyHomeCloud:~# echo "$?"
0
MyHomeCloud:~# e2fsck /dev/sda4
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda4 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
MyHomeCloud:~#
```

How can I `umount` so that I can `e2fsck`?

I am also trying to use `smartctl` which reports no problems on the short test but the long test will take about 14 hours and I have postponed doing that until I know for sure I need to run it.

EDIT 1:
I ran `mount` to see what directories were mounted on /dev/sda4:

```
MyHomeCloud:~# mount
/dev/root on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=40960k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=40960k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=102400k,nr_inodes=20480)
/dev/root on /var/log.hdd type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
ramlog-tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=40960k)
/dev/sda4 on /DataVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
/dev/sda4 on /CacheVolume type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
/dev/sda4 on /nfs/Public type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
/dev/sda4 on /nfs/DalesDesktop type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
/dev/sda4 on /nfs/TimeMachineBackup type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
MyHomeCloud:~#
```

Then I ran `lsof +D` on those directories with these results:

```
MyHomeCloud:~# lsof +D /DataVolume/
lsof: WARNING: can't lstat(/DataVolume/shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/Garmin): Input/output error
lsof: WARNING: can't lstat(/DataVolume/shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/Proton Development Suite/Proteus 7 Professional): Input/output error
MyHomeCloud:~# lsof +D /CacheVolume/
MyHomeCloud:~# lsof +D /nfs/Public/
MyHomeCloud:~# lsof +D /nfs/DalesDesktop/
lsof: WARNING: can't lstat(/nfs/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/Garmin): Input/output error
lsof: WARNING: can't lstat(/nfs/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/Proton Development Suite/Proteus 7 Professional): Input/output error
lsof: WARNING: can't lstat(/nfs/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-14/!---Dale/Keuka/SeeBoard/carm3.bmp): No child processes
lsof: can't fork: Cannot allocate memory
MyHomeCloud:~# lsof +D /nfs/TimeMachineBackup/
MyHomeCloud:~#
```

Did I use `lsof` properly?  I don't see any processes that need to be killed but it looks like I need to also fix something about the file carm3.bmp

ALSO, here is my /etc/fstab :

```
MyHomeCloud:~# cat /etc/fstab
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs defaults 0 0

## found that Access DLNA can sometimes temporarily use up to 70M of the /tmp space
## increasing to 100M maximum
## setting number of inodes to 20K
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,size=100M,nr_inodes=20K 0 0

/dev/md1 / ext3 defaults,noatime,nodiratime,data=writeback,barrier=0 0 0
MyHomeCloud:~#
```

I do not see anything that relates to /dev/sda4, am I interpreting this correctly?

Why does my /etc/fstab ONLY have /dev/md1 in it and why do the results of my `mount` query not even include /dev/md1 which is in /etc/fstab?

The `smartctl` long test completed in about 16 hours without error.

EDIT 2 : 
After finding this comment in my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
#
# Note: WD-NAS related post-boot finalization functionality is moved to /etc/init.d/wdInitFinalize script
#
```

I looked at the `/etc/init.d/wdInitFinalize` script.  I think this maybe the startup script that mounts /dev/sda4.  Being new to Linux I do not understand much in the script.

Can I just move this script to another directory and try rebooting?

WOW, now that WAS a bad idea.  I decided to just rename wdInitFinalize and then reboot.  Big mistake!! Reboot never accomplished.  Couldn't ssh to it, or use WD local web interface.  Thought it was bricked.  Had to open MyCloud case, take out drive, attach it to my Win7 computer by Sata cable, install Ext2Fsd so that I could eventually rename that file on the two system partitions, reassemble the MyCloud, do a '40 second button press' RESET of the MyCloud and then re input all my myCloud settings (most importantly enable ssh).  Only then was I back to where I started (with those few file system errors :).

----------------- SOLUTION - SOLUTION - SOLUTION - SOLUTION -----------------:

NOTE: I have learned that the easiest check that confirms that a `umount` was successful is to simply repeat the specific `umount`.  If the `umount` was successful, you will be rewarded with a message that tells you it is not mounted!

Here was the process (maybe can do less but this worked for me):

1  Do `fuser -vm` on all directories of the stubborn volume (/dev/sda4 in my case).  You can see those mounted directories using `mount`.

2  Kill all PIDs that fuser shows you.

3  `umount` all those directories individually (twice see above NOTE)

4  `umount` the stubborn volume itself (twice)

5  `e2fsck` the stubborn volume (with any - options like say -y to answer questions with y)

6  Just for extra caution I rebooted after fixing the errors.

Thanks to @psui for guiding me in this tedious effort!!

Here are the detailed commands I executed:

```
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# fuser -vm /DataVolume
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/DataVolume:         root     kernel mount /DataVolume
                     root       9363 F...m restsdk-server
                     root      16542 f.... lsof
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# kill 16542
-bash: kill: (16542) - No such process
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# kill 9363
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /DataVolume
umount: /DataVolume: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# fuser -vm /DataVolume
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/DataVolume:         root     kernel mount /DataVolume
                     root      10507 f.... du
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# kill 10507
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# fuser -vm /DataVolume
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/DataVolume:         root     kernel mount /DataVolume
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /DataVolume
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /DataVolume
umount: /DataVolume/: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /CacheVolume
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /CacheVolume
umount: /CacheVolume: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/Public
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/Public
umount: /nfs/Public: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/DalesDesktop
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/DalesDesktop
umount: /nfs/DalesDesktop: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/TimeMachineBackup
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/TimeMachineBackup
umount: /nfs/TimeMachineBackup: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# mount
/dev/root on / type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=40960k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=40960k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=102400k,nr_inodes=20480)
/dev/root on /var/log.hdd type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
ramlog-tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=40960k)
/dev/sda4 on /nfs/Dale type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=writeback)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw,relatime)
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/Dale
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /nfs/Dale
umount: /nfs/Dale: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# umount /dev/sda4
umount: /dev/sda4: not mounted
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d# e2fsck /dev/sda4
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda4 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 4456616 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 58261515 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 58261571 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 58261592 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 58261593 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 84607406 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 84607407 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Deleted inode 166068240 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 166068241 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 166068242 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 166068243 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 166068245 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 166068246 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 166068247 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 166068248 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 166068326 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 166068339 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Deleted inode 166068615 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Extended attribute block 1332744333 has reference count 4, should be 2.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry '..' in .../??? (4456624) has deleted/unused inode 4456618.  Clear<y>? yes
Entry 'Proteus 7 Professional' in /shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs/Proton Development Suite (90309235) has deleted/unused inode 100467315.  Clear<y>? yes
Entry 'Garmin' in /shares/DalesDesktop/e+/2015-12-26/Documents and Settings/All Users/Start Menu/Programs (4719331) has deleted/unused inode 85590643.  Clear<y>? yes
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Unconnected directory inode 4456624 (...)
Connect to /lost+found<y>? yes
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Inode 4456624 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 4719331 ref count is 4, should be 3.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23466035 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23466036 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23466037 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528078 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528079 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528080 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528081 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528082 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528083 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528084 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528085 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528086 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528087 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528088 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528089 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528090 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528091 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528092 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528093 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528094 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528095 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528096 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528097 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528098 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528099 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528100 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528101 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528102 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528103 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528104 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528105 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528106 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528107 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528108 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23528109 ref count is 16, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 32506004 ref count is 14, should be 13.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 32506005 ref count is 14, should be 13.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 32506015 ref count is 14, should be 13.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 58720627 ref count is 12, should be 11.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 90309235 ref count is 3, should be 2.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700859 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700860 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700861 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700862 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700863 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700864 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700865 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700866 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700867 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700868 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700869 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700870 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700884 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700885 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700913 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700914 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700915 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700916 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179700917 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701633 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701634 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701635 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701636 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701640 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701642 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701643 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 179701648 ref count is 14, should be 15.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -35656376 -466096174 -466096194 -466124842 -466124915 -466128388 -466128396 -466128399 -466128405 -466128410 -466130267 -466130269 -466130272 -466130275 -466130279 -466130286 -466130290 -466130296 -466130312 -466131490 -466131492 -466131495 -466131500 -676860386 -(676889088--676889089) -676889091 -676889094 -676889097 -676889101 -676889108 -676889112 -676889118 -676889134 -1328549952 -(1328550033--1328550034) -1328550301 -(1328578561--1328578568)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1088 (28278, counted=28279).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #14224 (27997, counted=27999).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #14225 (31816, counted=31836).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #20656 (27980, counted=27981).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #20657 (32758, counted=32768).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #20896 (28002, counted=28003).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #24528 (27998, counted=27999).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #24544 (27997, counted=27998).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #24560 (28002, counted=28003).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #40544 (28260, counted=28264).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #40545 (32758, counted=32766).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (1296055779, counted=1296055829).
Fix<y>? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -4456616 -58261515 -58261571 -(58261592--58261593) -(84607406--84607407) -(166068240--166068243) -(166068245--166068248) -166068326 -166068339 -166068615
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #1088 (3643, counted=3644).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #1088 (362, counted=361).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #14224 (3391, counted=3395).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #14224 (635, counted=633).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #20656 (3464, counted=3466).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #20656 (631, counted=630).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #20896 (3458, counted=3459).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #20896 (638, counted=637).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #24528 (3458, counted=3459).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #24528 (638, counted=637).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #24544 (3458, counted=3459).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #24544 (638, counted=637).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #24560 (3458, counted=3459).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #24560 (638, counted=637).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #40544 (3706, counted=3717).
Fix<y>? yes
Directories count wrong for group #40544 (377, counted=374).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (181303937, counted=181303959).
Fix<y>? yes

/dev/sda4: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda4: 1693033/182996992 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 167896043/1463951872 blocks
MyHomeCloud:/etc/init.d#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop using the volume in order to unmount it.  You can track down programs that still hold files open on that volume with `lsof` and then kill them.  Also it should have been fscked automatically before mounting it.  Make sure the fsck order ( next to last colum ) for the volume in /etc/fstab is not set to zero as this disables the automatic fsck.

Comment: Please see EDIT 1 in question.

Comment: @KiloOne, well if you are manually mounting it after the system boots up, then that would also explain why it wasn't fscked.  Simply reboot and fsck it before mounting.

Comment: Sorry, i do not mount it after boot-up.  It must be magic :)

Comment: I am new to Linux, @psusi where can I look to find out why /dev/sda4 gets mounted automatically on boot up?

Comment: @KiloOne, wait... the unmount command did not fail?  Yet it still shows up in mount as mounted?  Can you still see the files in that directory or is it empty?  If it is empty, then my guess is that you have a corrupt/out of date /etc/mtab ( and it isn't just a symlink to /proc/mounts as it should be on modern distros, which prevents this from happening ).  If it is still visible then try unmounting it by directory rather than device name.

Comment: I was assuming that my umount command failed even though my `echo "$?"` query did return 0.  Being a novice I just assumed you saw that and it was an anomaly.  After all, after that my umount said it was still mounted.  Anyway, after the unount I am still able to navigate through directories and still see the bad Garmin directory so I guess it really did not umount.   When I try `umount /DataVolume` the response is `device is busy`, very interesting, why is it busy?  `losf +D` on that directory is shown in question.  Does just the fact that there are bad directories make it think it is busy?

Comment: @KiloOne, well since there is nothing in your /etc/fstab that should cause /DataVolume to be mounted, and you seem to be using a cloud/vps provider, I would say that what you are looking at is actually an lxc container that has some non standard mechanism that exists outside of the container that is causing the volume to be mounted, without being fscked, and keeping it in use so you can not unmount it to fsck it, and so you will have to take it up with the provider.  Unless you can run `lsof` with `sudo` and get it to identify a process that you can see as using /DataVolume and kill it.

Comment: That really helped me, see detailed solution in question, thanks!!!